# Vector field as irreducible representation of Lorentz group

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

It is said that vector field is $(1/2,1/2)$ representation of the Lorentz group, thus it is $(2\times\frac{1}{2}+1)\times(2\times\frac{1}{2}+1)=4$ dimensional. However, in trying to quantize the field, we say there are only 3 degrees of the freedom of the field. Why do we only need to quantize a 3-dimensional field instead of a 4-dimensional field?

It is said that the $(1/2,1/2)$ representation of the Lorentz group falls into $1\oplus 0$ representation upon restricting to $SO(3)$ group. My understanding is that vector field, with its 3 degrees of freedom, actually belongs to this 1 representation of the $SO(3)$ group. But why do we need to restrict to $SO(3)$? Why don't we study the full Poincare group?

Comment: It is said where? Which page?

Comment: When the vector field is massless it will depend on only 3 degrees of freedom. The fourth is removed by the zero mass condition.

Comment: It is said in the Schwartz QFT book, chapter8 and chapter10